# Difference between function() and new Function()

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

while searching around the internet i found two ways of writing javascript function.

One is `Function()` constructor

```
var myFunction = new Function("a", "b", "return a * b");

var x = myFunction(4, 3);
```

Second is simple defining function

```
var myFunction = function (a, b) {return a * b};

var x = myFunction(4, 3);
```

When i used above both method i found no difference between these 2.

Is there any difference between these 2 or is there any use of using function constructor??

Comment: The first form will not have access to any locally-scoped variables. Also, it is less efficient, because it has to be parsed at run-time. In general, there is no reason to use it.

Comment: First one is converting an arbitrary string into an executable function. Not secure unless string is already validated.

Comment: And you could have searched for that, couldn't you? At 3000+ reputation I would actually expect that you search first.

Comment: @Tomalak i suggest you to read the question carefully...the question you marked as duplicate is about declaring a function into a variable..and i asked about difference between declaring a function simply and with `new Function()` constructor...read question carefully before marking as duplicate

Comment: `new Function()` can be used to pass the function's body in a string. And hence this can be used to create dynamic functions. 

Also passing the script without executing the script.

Comment: @Trying2Learn is there any relevant example for your statement..

Comment: @GauravAggarwal plz go to this link stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/37131496#37131496. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand why you all are relating this question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname this question that us different thing about parsing a function in variable but i am here talking about Function() constructor.

Comment: I resist the temptation to search a duplicate question (or - gasp - the documentation) for what `new Function()` means.

Comment: Reopened, since the proposed duplicate had nothing to do with the question. This does not mean this question _isn't_ a duplicate, it was just not an appropriate target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)**: When using the
>   Function() constructor, you pass the parameter names first (as 
>   strings) and then the source code for the body of the function (again 
>   as a string). The JavaScript engine needs to evaluate the source code 
>   you pass and create the new function for you. This source code 
>   evaluation suffers from the same drawbacks **as the eval()** function,
>   so defining functions using the Function() constructor should be 
>   avoided when possible.

```
 var first = new Function(
     'a, b, c, d',
     'return arguments;'
 );

 first(1, 2, 3, 4); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

 var second = new Function(
     'a, b, c',
     'd',
     'return arguments;'
 );

 second(1, 2, 3, 4); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

 var third = new Function(
     'a',
     'b',
     'c',
     'd',
     'return arguments;'
 );

 third(1, 2, 3, 4); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> **Best practice: Do not use the Function() constructor. As with eval()
>    and setTimeout(), always try to stay away from passing JavaScript code
>    as a string.**

What is the difference? See @Greg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/603774)